# Recover Exchange 2007 Storage group from EBD

Tags: exchange, edb

Is there a way to restore the exchange 2007 storage group from an edb with no log files?

My exchange server crashed and all I have is the .EDB file.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

From my limited knowledge I believe you will have to run an integrity check on the .edb and mount it again. Not sure if you will need to delete the checkpoint file. Having no log files, you will lose any info that was in log files but not yet committed to the .edb.

Answer (score 1):

If it's not too awfully late already, you can try the Kernel Exchange EDB Viewer. With this free tool you can look into your Exchange database and make sure it's still readable. If it is you could use the file straight away within an Exchange Server environment to access all your data.

If not you'll have to find some (usually expensive) tools which can save as much of your Exchange database as possible.